# Envoy proxy server : how to preserve socket options?

Tags: istio, envoyproxy

So, I need to set DSCP byte for HTTP/2 traffic on client side, which is an IP header. This is easily done using setsockopt IP_TOS on the socket sending the HTTP POST request.

But, we are using istio in our project, hence all traffic goes through envoy proxy, and I verified that the envoy proxy is stripping away all IP headers when proxying.

Ie, client sends http post to envoy with DSCP set -> envoy sends HTTP post to the actual recipient, but all IP headers set by setsockopt is gone.

Looking at envoy documentation, it seems that the solution is to use a 'tcp filter', and envoy already has a selection of filters inbuilt: https://github.com/envoyproxy/envoy/tree/main/source/extensions/transport_sockets

But, sadly, the documentation is quite cryptic. But this must be a common requirement, so does anyone know how to get envoy to preserve IP headers set by setsockopt?

Thank you for any advice!

Answer (score 1):

I think you can try config CLUSTER’s upstream_bind_config by using istio envoyfilter API, the related doc are here. I did not try it, but seems it is what you need.

https://www.envoyproxy.io/docs/envoy/latest/api-v3/config/cluster/v3/cluster.proto.html?highlight=bindconfig
https://www.envoyproxy.io/docs/envoy/latest/api-v3/config/core/v3/address.proto#envoy-v3-api-msg-config-core-v3-bindconfig
https://www.envoyproxy.io/docs/envoy/latest/api-v3/config/core/v3/socket_option.proto#envoy-v3-api-msg-config-core-v3-socketoption

Comment: Thanks, but not exactly what I need... this hardcodes socket option for all connections, in my case the application will be setting one per request.  It looks like I will have to add a filter that 'getsockopt's the inbound socket and sets it in the outbound socket.

Comment: but both inbound/outbound socket options (etc. DSCP) is set by yourself through envoyfilter yaml. Or do you mean you want to get DSCP from client (set by client socket options) and then in the server side (envoyproxy) to read it back and then set to envoyproxy outbound socket?
in fact, I don't think it is support DSCP configuration perf request, it shall at least per connection, and for outbound (cluster connection pool), it will be per cluster connection pool. for inbound, there is only one server socket one listener/port which support multiple connections from different client sockets?

Comment: Yeah, we wanted DSCP to be configured by client per request, so only for outbound connections, ultimately we went with have client configuring the envoy filter to set DSCP on the outbound socket.